# MSO/MSE header bar

Tags: discussion, bug, meta, design, top-bar

I have no problems with (and support) the new MSO/MSE changes, but noted the bold version of headers for MSO:

[image]

And then plain text for MSE:

[image]

Standardisation miss? - or just style changes/differentiation as I found myself squinting at headers earlier in getting used to this brave new (world|format).

Comment: My top bar is not bolded anywhere... Do you have custom styles enabled?

Comment: Nope, nada, nowhere. Hard-refreshed in Chrome(iOS). Will try in other browsers/OS.

Comment: @animuson, Repro'd in Safari on iOS too.

Comment: Hrm. No repro on iOS in Safari. What version of iOS and which device are you on?

Comment: Chrome: Version 34.0.1847.116
Safari: 5.1.1 (6534.51.22)
Both on web on OSX 10.6.8 (older but reliable!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither are bolded, but the antialiasing settings are different. In Meta Stack Exchange, and Meta Stack Exchange only, this line is included in `all.css`:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

This changes the text rendering method used, and since this line is not present on Meta Stack Overflow, the header looks slightly different between the two sites.